# What is [ember-old-router] and why does it exist?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Today, 77 questions were retagged to [ember-old-router](/questions/tagged/ember-old-router).  There is no tag wiki.

There is nothing inside [ember-router](/questions/tagged/ember-router), the previous tag these questions held, to suggest that it is "new" or that there is a previous iteration of it that deserves or requires its own tag.  There is nothing in [the Ember.Router API guide](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html) that suggests that there is a previous iteration that deserves or requires different tagging, or how to identify it.

In fact, there is only mention of a *new* router anywhere on the internet, not an *old* router.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14186092/168868), for example, mentions the changes.  In fact, it points at [a different section of the manual](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) that explains the new way of doing things.  Apparently they haven't even updated the API guide.  Thanks, Ember.js.

We have three problems now:

1. Ember.js has completely changed their router API in a backwards incompatable way.  They have done so in a pre-1.0 version, which makes using version-specific tags a bit sticky.  This makes classifying router questions here on SO rather irritating to say the least.
2. The new tag name *sucks* and is effectively undiscoverable.  How do I know whem I'm using the "old" router?  Where was the tag wiki?  If this was important enough to retag *over half* of the applicable questions under an old tag, why wasn't at least an excerpt made?
3. The mass retagging seems to have been done without pinging Meta for sanity.  Why was a tag for the "old" router created instead of one for the "new" router?

I'd like to:

1. <strike>Get ahold of the retagger and ask for clarification</strike>.  Pinged.
2. Discuss alternative ways to classify the two types of router question, and
3. Nuke the new tag in favor of something more *clear*.

Comment: Point 1 is done? Where? Any info to share. Or did you just contact?

Comment: I pinged him @-style on one of the questions.  Same user on all of'em.

Comment: Ah okay, let's see then. This is a weird one.

Answer (score 12):

I would first apologize for this, I didn't think users would be such disturbed. In fact Ember.js is close to 1.0, at least the team will do an 1.0.pre-3 in few days.

I decided to retag to ember-old-router (the retag is not completely done yet) because the routing system has completely changed since the 1.0.pre-2, and searching with [ember-router] will confuse users about the syntax.

Perhaps the term is very messy, but I didn't find better.

BTW, I have written a minor description of the tag, explaining to users that the questions/answers are outdated, and could be updated. Unfortunately, this description should be approved, as I see it does not appear.

One more time, I'm so sorry, I would just help... I have still to learn.
Any idea is welcome in order to doing this better.

I don't like the 'new-router' too, since for me ember-router should reference the current routing system.

Comment: Agree with the whole position. +1

Comment: Since the new router is called V2, maybe the old router should use the name "ember-router-v1", and then the new could be tagged "ember-router-v2"?

Comment: Seems pretty good to me. I asked ember contributors to take a look at this question. I should probably have to do it before changing anything :s

Comment: Are you on the ember.js team?  If so, fantastic job—it looks like an amazing js framework.

Comment: No I'm not in the team, just an enthusiast player which try to help the community about it. Here unfortunately it seems I've goofed :(

Comment: I—and the community from the looks of the votes you're getting—agree with how you handled this.  It *may* of been better to name the tag [ember-router-beta] but I don't think it's a huge deal.

Comment: don't worry too much meta likes to pretend they own things and have power, but really 95% of SO users would have done the same thing

Comment: @Ryathal thanks :), though I think Charles question is legit. I will see later what I'll do for remaining outdated questions.

Comment: My main concern was just the choice of name / directionality of the retag and that so many questions were retagged at once.  It's usually good to check with meta if you're going to clean up more than a few dozen questions.  Some people can get a bit worried about mass retaggings.  *Is* the new router actually called "v2"?

Comment: @Charles The next time I'll be sure to ask a question here. This was the first for me doing this kind of thing. BTW, I think I've just finish to clean this up. I ping Tom Dale about it. He should come here to explain the point of view. Some people are agree with the naming.

Comment: If it's gonna make sense to the folks that live and breathe Ember.js, then I'm going to stop my whining.  To the outside world, the current tag is *poorly named* and nigh-undiscoverable.  I look forward to it being made sense of...

Answer (score 9):

Ember.js core team member here.

Let me first give a little bit of history.

Ember.js is quickly approaching its 1.0 release. On the path from 0.1 to 1.0, we've done a lot of experimentation with our APIs, with the explicit warning that these APIs are *subject to change at any time!*

The flip side of our willingness to futz with the API pre-1.0 is that we can be extremely conservative about API changes post-1.0.

That's what you're seeing right now. First, we had our first implementation of the router API (which is colloquially referred to as "v1"). Then, we transitioned to a radically different version, referred to as "v2". Once that landed, we've spent the last two or three weeks iterating on "v2", which have respectively been called "v2.1", "v2.2", etc. The most recent version is the final version that will ship with Ember.js 1.0, and should henceforth just be referred to as "the Ember.js routing API."

Every old version of the routing API is dead and deprecated. They will not be supported, and  there is no support for backwards compatibility. Everyone should migrate to the new router API as soon as possible. In accordance with the SemVer spec, future versions of Ember (1.1, 1.2, etc.) *will* maintain compatibility with the Ember.js 1.0 routing API.

> Ember.js has completely changed their router API in a backwards incompatable way. They have done so in a pre-1.0 version, which makes using version-specific tags a bit sticky. This makes classifying router questions here on SO rather irritating to say the least

SemVer allows us to make breaking API changes pre-1.0. We now have our 1.0 API that people should be building against. We should make sure that anyone searching StackOverflow right now is lead towards answers that use the new router API. It should be made obvious that answers using any of the older versions of the routing API are deprecated and unsupported.

> The new tag name sucks and is effectively undiscoverable. How do I know whem I'm using the "old" router? Where was the tag wiki? If this was important enough to retag over half of the applicable questions under an old tag, why wasn't at least an excerpt made?

How do other projects handle breaking API changes to pre-1.0 releases? I am open to suggestions for a different tag name, but there are no situations anyone should be using the "old" router, especially now that it is a few months old.

> The mass retagging seems to have been done without pinging Meta for sanity. Why was a tag for the "old" router created instead of one for the "new" router?

The "new" router is the canonical router. Users getting started with the framework now should not need to know the difference between the new router and the old router; it is just "the router."

Comment: Great answer, Tom.  The *usual* way to handle changed APIs is to use a versioned tag somewhere in the question, when the version actually matters.  In the case of the router API, it's totally going to matter.  However, "old" is a vague term to use as part of the tag name.  Can we come up with a better way to name the tag?  The only ones I can think of don't really flow, like `ember-router-pre-1.0`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, it's better with the whole history, and probably better when it comes from a core member :) @Charles, probably ember-router-pre-1.0 will be ok as soon as the 1.0 is shipped. Currently even some recent questions from 15 days are already no more relevant. Perhaps I could rename the tag, and completely finish the clean up when the the 1.0 api is finished.

Comment: IMHO `ember-router-pre-1.0` could still potentially mislead people who might think this tag name would refer to the state of the routing API before Ember 1.0, but there are two distinct routing APIs which were released before Ember is reached 1.0, so I would say `ember-router-v1` (or even `ember-router-draft`) for the "old" router, and  `ember-router` would be a little more descriptive. But that's just my opinion.